# Как прокрутку страницы прикрепить к прокрутке конкретного блока

Tags: html, css

На странице есть блок с новостями, к которому применены следующие стили:

```css
.main_body{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: calc(100% - 150px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Необходимо, чтобы при наполнении его контентом и появлением скролла, полоса прокрутки была глобальной, то есть как у всей страницы, но прокрутка шла именно этого блока

Comment: @Sevastopol' Нужно прокручивать только этот блок. Основной контент на нём. Все остальные блоки можно оставить на месте. Но если им сделать position: fixed, то вся структура слетает, поэтому появилась глобальным скроллом прокручивать только этот необходимый блок.

Comment: Как я понял, тебе нужно стилизовать полосу прокрутки, чтобы она выглядела как основная. Для этого в браузерах на webkit можно использовать псевдоэлементы `::-webkit-scrollbar-*`, в других - никак. Хотя правильное решение - использование фиксированного или абсолютного позиционирования

Comment: @Dan Sazonov, Окей, спасибо, буду думать.